# Address with hyphen or back slash separator

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expressions. I have an address field and this address field should accept `-` or `/` as separators, and a full stop (`.`) when it occurs as the last character.

These should be accepted:

> A-8/1
>
> A/1/b
>
> testaddress

But it should not accept all other special characters other than these two: `-` or `/` (and final stop: `.`). Furthermore, a slash or hyphen should not be consecutive, nor appear at the very start or end of the address. Also, the address is in US English, so accented letters should not be allowed.

I am using the following regular expression:

```
^\w+(?:[\/,-]\w+)*.{0,1}$
```

But the problem is that it is accepting all other special characters.

How should I correct my regular expression?

Comment: `^\w+(?:[/-]\w+)*$`

Comment: I am getting error / Unescaped delimiter. I think it should be 
^\w+(?:[\/-]\w+)*$

Comment: Even simpler: `([\w\/-]+)`

Comment: This one : [`^([\w \/-]*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/pL4iI5/1)

Comment: No Java doesn't require escaping /

Comment: in this case ([\w\/-]+) it will accept /- without any words which is not valid there should be some words before these characters.

Comment: I don't understand why -1 it is a valid question.

Comment: I did not downvote, but there is no problem statement. You should mention what the problem is with the regular expression you use, and give an example where it goes wrong. Also, what is "special": are accented letters special, are Greek characters special, is a comma or point special... ? From your regex it seems you don't want two consecutive slashes or hyphens or a combination or both, and that they should not occur at the very start or end. Please be precise in your requirements.

Comment: After your edit: Please describe in words what your requirements are. They are incomplete (see my previous comment). Also, why did you change the regular expression so dramatically? Is this the (final) one you are asking about now? NB: At this point I added my downvote.

Comment: My requirement is if user enters address with slash (/) and/or hyphen (-) and full stop(.) at the end it should validate the address other than this throw invalid address message.

Comment: Please read my first comment. Several unanswered questions. Greek? Accented? Or don't you expect Spanish addresses ( ñ ), ...? Can there be two consecutive slashes, hyphen followed by slash, ... etc, etc. Please be specific, and put it in your question. NB: regular expressions don't *throw* anything.

Comment: slash or hyphen should not be consecutive and the address is US English.

Comment: What about spaces, can they be consecutive? is a combination slash-space-slash allowed? Are multiple lines allowed? Are spaces allowed on either side of a hyphen or a slash? If multi-line, can a hyphen or slash occur at the start or end of a line, ... I repeat: you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several specifications missing, but here is a regular expression you could use:

```
/^([a-z0-9]+\s*[-\/]?\s*)*[a-z0-9]+\.?$/i
```

The `i` modifier makes the match case-insensitive.

[Regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/uW1hK5/1).

If you don't accept spaces at either side of a separator, and don't accept repeated spaces, then it becomes:

```
^([a-z0-9]+[-\/\s]?)*[a-z0-9]+\.?$
```

[Regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/uW1hK5/2)